# Cloudformation If with two Or

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a CFN template with the following block:

```
- Fn::If:
   - PreDefinedCondition1
   - !Ref ValueIfTrue
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

I have a 2nd condition and I want the If function to evaluate either condition using `Fn::Or` but it keeps failing with a message that If expects a string or condition. This is what I am trying to achieve

```
- Fn::If:
   - Fn::Or
     - PreDefinedCondition1
     - PreDefinedCondition2
   - !Ref ValueIfTrue
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Both `PreDefinedCondition1` and `PreDefinedCondition2` are already defined under the `Conditions:` block in the same template.

In simpler language, "if PreDefinedCondition1 !Or PreDefinedCondition2, assign ValueIfTrue" How do I achieve this in Cloudformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create new condition in your `Conditions` section. For example:

```
Conditions:

    PreDefinedCondition1:
        !Equals [1, 1]
        
    PreDefinedCondition2:
        !Equals [1, 1]   
        
    Cond1OrCond2:
        !Or [Condition: PreDefinedCondition1, Condition: PreDefinedCondition2]
```

Then, later you just use `Cond1OrCond2`:

```
- Fn::If:
   - Cond1OrCond2
   - !Ref ValueIfTrue
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Comment: cfn-lint fails with `Fn::Or list must be another valid condition` - yet the conditions are valid

Comment: @Saichovsky Can you update your question? What are `PreDefinedCondition1` and `PreDefinedCondition2`?

Comment: Done. The two conditions are already defined. Previously, we had PreDefinedCondition1 under Fn::If, but I want to add the second PreDefinedCondition2 to the same If function